# Error Code 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value al updatear una columna en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando actualizar una columna de una de mis tablas de MySql de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me esta dando el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en el valor que estoy intentado actualizar

Comment: ¿Y si lo encierras entre comillas dobles tambien?    Es decir, a partir de `custom_config=` le pones unas comillas antes del parentesis, y unas al final despues del ultimo parentesis antes del `where`

Comment: si hago eso las comillas se cierran con las que están justo después del styles

Comment: Entonces tendras que escaparlas con una barra invertida \ antes todas ellas, excepto las que tengas al principio y al final que te he dicho.  Es decir, `\"` en lugar de `"`

Comment: Claro!! es verdad, siempre se me olvida los escape. con esto ha funcionado muchas gracias

Comment: Pon el error _como texto, con formato_, y también escríbelo en el título, para que otras personas con el mismo problema puedan llegar a ella. Además, no olvides responder a la pregunta y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @exferos He agregado una respuesta con un poco de explicación para que conste que está respondida correctamente. Si la respuesta soluciona a tu pregunta acéptala tal como dice padelaina, así no quedará pendiente eternamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según parece tienes el **típico problema de escape de caracteres entrecomillados**.

La consulta que te da error es con este formato aproximadamente:

```
update table_namexxxx set custom_config = ('cadena' con "comillas" incluidas || y 'otras cosas' etc) where id=164;
```

La cual **no estaba entrecomillada** en la igualdad del primer campo (*custom_config*) del `set`, ni al principio (antes del paréntesis de apertura) ni al final (después del paréntesis de cierre).

Al hacerlo te ha dado un nuevo error, por **no escapar las comillas coincidentes** con el entrecomillado escogido, en este caso las comillas dobles.

La forma de escapar las comillas conflictivas es mediante una barra invertida **\**.

Por lo tanto, la consulta correcta podia ser esta:

```
update table_namexxxx set custom_config = "('cadena' con \"comillas\" incluidas || y 'otras cosas' etc)" where id=164;
```

o bien esta (si la encerramos entre comillas simples):

```
update table_namexxxx set custom_config = '(\'cadena\' con "comillas" incluidas || y \'otras cosas\' etc)' where id=164;
```